# Sill of vinyl replacement windows loose: Does this require a window replacement?

Tags: windows

The window sill shows a big gap and moves when I press on it. This is the vinyl part of the window, not the wooden trim. There are no gaps from the exterior. It is possible that the space below the front edge of the sill was always hollow. Now a screw (which I can see in the gap) came off and the sill gets pressed down.

- Is this a common problem with older vinyl replacement windows?
- Would you replace the window?

[image]

Comment: Clean the edges inside the opening as best as you can, squeeze some silicon caulking in there and tape the two pieces together.